How to detect Braille Screen Input "quick action" for sending message
According to Apple support documentation, when using Braille Screen Input, swiping up with three fingers will "enter a carriage return, or send a message". I am working on a messaging app and wondering how to detect this action so that I can perform a send message action as expected by the user.
Currently this action just inserts a new line. I thought perhaps if I could detect a carriage return specifically then I could use that but it seems like it inserts a \n identically to a two finger swipe to the right.
Some documentation suggests this works primarily for iMessage but I observe that WhatsApp also supports this behaviour so I am wondering if I am missing something.
